# str_replace in decoding function not working

Tags: php

The search and replace part of the function isn't working for some reason. Is my syntax wrong?

```
function display($data) {

$new = str_replace('<br />',"\n",$data);
$newer = htmlspecialchars($new);
    $search  = array('&lt;b&gt;', '&lt;/b&gt;', '&lt;i&gt;', '&lt;/i&gt;', '&lt;u&gt;', '&lt;/u&gt;', '\r\n');
    $replace = array('<b>', '</b>', '<i>', '</i>', '<u>', '</u>', '<br />');

  $newest = str_replace($replace, $search, $newer);

  return $newest;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `$data` to start with?

Comment: Look at the argument order: http://php.net/str_replace The manual is quicker and easier than SO.

Comment: Wow! How on earth did that get reversed?? This is a modification of a copy and pasted function I created earlier that works fine. I have no idea why those got reversed from the way they were in the original. So weird!

Comment: Why not use `nl2br()` instead of `str_replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it at this way:

```
function display($data) {

$new = str_replace('<br />',"\n",$data);
$newer = htmlspecialchars($new);
$replace = array('<b>' => '&lt;b&gt;', '</b>' => '&lt;/b&gt;', '<i>' => '&lt;i&gt;', '</i>'=> '&lt;/i&gt;', '<u>' => '&lt;u&gt;', '</u>' => '&lt;/u&gt;', '<br />' => '\r\n');
$newest = $newer;

foreach($replace as $rep => $find){
     $newest = str_replace($rep , $find, $newest);
}
  return $newest;
}
```